# Mule Flow fails on first try but works after with the LDAP connector

Tags: java, xml, ldap, mule

I have a strange behavior with my Mule flow. It is the only one that does this and I have no idea why. I use the LDAP connector. When I try the next day the first try to the listener fails and I get the error that follows:

```
ERROR 2015-05-29 08:34:44,115 [[reptel].HTTP_Listener_Configuration.worker.04] org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : Registered authentication is set to org.mule.module.spring.security.filters.http.HttpBasicAuthenticationFilter but there was no security context on the session. Authentication denied on endpoint none. Message payload is of type: NullPayload
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
1. Registered authentication is set to org.mule.module.spring.security.filters.http.HttpBasicAuthenticationFilter but there was no security context on the session. Authentication denied on endpoint none. Message payload is of type: NullPayload (org.mule.api.security.UnauthorisedException)
  org.mule.transport.http.filters.HttpBasicAuthenticationFilter:156 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/security/UnauthorisedException.html)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
org.mule.api.security.UnauthorisedException: Registered authentication is set to org.mule.module.spring.security.filters.http.HttpBasicAuthenticationFilter but there was no security context on the session. Authentication denied on endpoint none. Message payload is of type: NullPayload
    at org.mule.transport.http.filters.HttpBasicAuthenticationFilter.authenticateInbound(HttpBasicAuthenticationFilter.java:156)
    at org.mule.security.AbstractEndpointSecurityFilter.authenticate(AbstractEndpointSecurityFilter.java:54)
    at org.mule.security.AbstractAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationFilter.java:52)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
********************************************************************************

WARN  2015-05-29 08:34:50,111 [[reptel].HTTP_Listener_Configuration.worker.04] org.mule.module.ldap.api.jndi.LDAPJNDIConnection: Search failed.
INFO  2015-05-29 08:34:50,111 [[reptel].HTTP_Listener_Configuration.worker.04] org.mule.module.ldap.api.jndi.LDAPJNDIConnection: Connection dude@host.host@ldap://host.host.host:389/ closed.
ERROR 2015-05-29 08:34:50,111 [[reptel].HTTP_Listener_Configuration.worker.04] org.mule.retry.notifiers.ConnectNotifier: Failed to connect/reconnect: Work Descriptor. Root Exception was: Connection reset. Type: class java.net.SocketException
ERROR 2015-05-29 08:34:50,111 [[reptel].HTTP_Listener_Configuration.worker.04] org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : Failed to invoke search. Message payload is of type: NullPayload
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
1. Connection reset (java.net.SocketException)
  java.net.SocketInputStream:-1 (null)
2. javax.naming.CommunicationException: Connection reset [Root exception is java.net.SocketException: Connection reset]; remaining name 'OU=Musee,DC=mus, DC=civ'; resolved object com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx@2ba8e4bc (javax.naming.CommunicationException)
  com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx:-1 (http://java.sun.com/j2ee/sdk_1.3/techdocs/api/javax/naming/CommunicationException.html)
3. Connection reset (org.mule.module.ldap.api.CommunicationException)
  sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl:-2 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/module/ldap/api/CommunicationException.html)
4. Failed to invoke search. Message payload is of type: NullPayload (org.mule.api.MessagingException)
  org.mule.devkit.processor.DevkitBasedMessageProcessor:128 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/MessagingException.html)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
********************************************************************************
```

When I call it the second time it always works and I don't know for how much time but it continues working even from another browser were the auth session isn't there it works on the first try after that

Here is the flow :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:smtp="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/smtp" xmlns:scripting="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting" xmlns:file="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file" xmlns:json="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json" xmlns:data-mapper="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/data-mapper" xmlns:wmq="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/wmq" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http"
    xmlns:tracking="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="CE-3.6.1"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:spring-security="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/spring-security"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:ldap="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ldap"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking/current/mule-tracking-ee.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ldap http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ldap/current/mule-ldap.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/wmq http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/wmq/current/mule-wmq-ee.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/data-mapper http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/data-mapper/current/mule-data-mapper.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json/current/mule-json.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file/current/mule-file.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting/current/mule-scripting.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/smtp http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/smtp/current/mule-smtp.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/spring-security http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/spring-security/current/mule-spring-security.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">
    <ldap:config name="ldapConf" url="ldap://host.host.host:389/" authDn="dude@host.host" authPassword="password" doc:name="LDAP"/>
    <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="host" port="8084" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>

    <spring:beans>
        <security:authentication-manager alias="secAuthSample">  
            <security:authentication-provider> 
                <security:user-service id="authService"> 
                    <security:user name="ldap" password="ldap" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
                </security:user-service> 
            </security:authentication-provider> 
        </security:authentication-manager>
    </spring:beans>

    <spring-security:security-manager>
        <spring-security:delegate-security-provider name="memory-provider" delegate-ref="secAuthSample"/>
    </spring-security:security-manager>

    <flow name="activedirectoryGetUsers">       
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/ldap" doc:name="HTTP">        
            <http:response-builder>
                <http:header headerName="content-type" value="text/plain"/>
                <http:header headerName="Content-Disposition" value="attachment;filename=0544#[function:datestamp:yyyyMMdd].csv"/>
            </http:response-builder>
        </http:listener>
        <spring-security:http-security-filter realm="" securityProviders="memory-provider"/>
        <ldap:search config-ref="ldapConf" doc:name="LDAP" baseDn="OU=Musee,DC=mus, DC=civ" filter="(&amp;(objectClass=user)(Company=*dasdasd)(!(extensionAttribute11=asdasd))(!(extensionAttribute12=asdasd)))" scope="SUB_TREE" pageSize="200000000" maxResults="20000000">
          <ldap:attributes>
                <ldap:attribute>dn</ldap:attribute>
                <ldap:attribute>GivenName</ldap:attribute>
                <ldap:attribute>sn</ldap:attribute>
                <ldap:attribute>mail</ldap:attribute>
                <ldap:attribute>telephonenumber</ldap:attribute>
                <ldap:attribute>l</ldap:attribute>     
                <ldap:attribute>st</ldap:attribute>
                <ldap:attribute>postalCode</ldap:attribute>
                <ldap:attribute>streetAddress</ldap:attribute>      
        </ldap:attributes> 
    </ldap:search>
    <collection-splitter doc:name="Split Result Set"/>
    <ldap:ldap-entry-to-map doc:name="to LDIF"/>
    <collection-aggregator failOnTimeout="false" doc:name="Aggregate entries"/>
        <scripting:component doc:name="Groovy">
            <scripting:script engine="Groovy" file="adtocsv.groovy"></scripting:script>
        </scripting:component>
        <message-properties-transformer
overwrite="true" doc:name="Message Properties">
<add-message-property key="Content-Type"
value="text/plain;charset=ISO-8859-1;" />
<add-message-property key="MULE_ENCODING" value="ISO-8859-1" />
</message-properties-transformer>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

Comment: What version of the LDAP Connector do you use?

Comment: I use mule-module-ldap-1.3.1

Comment: This is the latest version... the issue you're facing sounds like a bug, I don't see anything wrong in your config, so it's worth taking it to MuleSoft IMO.

Comment: Damn that's too bad. I'll report it then. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, did you resolve this issue?